# "Mage" file in magento root

Tags: php, magento

I currently have Magento set up on a development server (remote, SSH access). I would like to understand what is the "mage" file in the magento root? How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mage is generally place in magento dir. This file has   import role in magento
see file at https://github.com/speedupmate/Magento-CE-Mirror/blob/master/mage

Comment: Thanks for reply. I finally figured out what it is for.. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

It's just a bash configuration script that sets up some basic PHP stuff. It's included with every install. Beyond that I'm not sure what you're asking specifically...